# How can i download tkinter without any package manager?

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, yocto

I'm working on a weird yocto linux build which dosen't have any package manager. How can i download tkiner to my SoC? Normally i would just compile it but the build appears to not have the GNU Coreutils either....

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Yocto's `python3` recipe generates a [`python3-tkinter` package](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python3/python3-manifest.json?h=honister#n1155). You can add that to `IMAGE_INSTALL` to have tkinter installed in your image.

However, tkinter requires python3 to be built with `tk`, and so you'll need to enable that via `PACKAGECONFIG` and add the `meta-openembedded/meta-oe` layer to your build which contains the `tk` recipe:

```
# local.conf
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " python3-tkinter"
PACKAGECONFIG:append:pn-python3 = " tk"
```